# I need an awful rule (awesome-wm 4.X) to match a web browser javascript dialog

Tags: awesome-wm, lua

I need help creating a rule to match a javascript dialog window, here is a portion of the output from xprop:

```
...
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "wb", "Wb"
WM_ICON_NAME(STRING) = "JavaScript - http://localhost/folder/map2.html"
_NET_WM_ICON_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "JavaScript - http://localhost/folder/map2.html"
WM_NAME(STRING) = "JavaScript - http://localhost/folder/map2.html"
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "JavaScript - http://localhost/folder/map2.html"
```

The browser window itself has the same class "Wb" and since I just want to match the dialog window and not the browser window I cannot use something like this:

```
{ rule = { class = "Wb" }, properties = {floating = true}, callback = function(c) awful.placement.centered(c,nil) end},
```

I also cannot try to match the name since that will be different for each page.  I'm not that familiar with lua, can you match a substring in a rule, something like:

```
{ rule = { "JavaScript - http://" in name }, properties = {floating = true}, callback = function(c) awful.placement.centered(c,nil) end},
```

Comment: It's nice that you tell us you can't do something but what is the actual question? What are you even using or trying to accomplish under which constraints on what platform? You might want to check again [how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: As an awesome user (heh), I think I understand the question. They're asking how to match a window with the given xprops, and show both what they've tried and what (in pseudo-Lua syntax) what they are trying to do to match the window properly. +1

Comment: Thank you l0b0 for verifying the completeness and clarity of my question. Seth, don't let your ignorance on a topic turn you into a hater. :)